# Change Url using Regex

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have url, for example:

> **http://i.myhost.com/myimage.jpg**

I want to change this url to

> http://i.myhost.com/myimage**D**.jpg.

**(Add D after image name and before point)**

i.e I want add some words after image name and before point using regex.
What is the best way do it using regex?

Comment: Do you need solution via regex only or simple parsing of a url will do as well?

Comment: Need solution via regex only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `^(.*)\.([a-zA-Z]{3,5})` and replacing with `\1D\2`. I'm assuming the extension is 3-5 alphanumeric numbers but you can modify it to suit. E.g. if it's just `jpg` images then you can put that instead of the `[a-zA-Z]{3,5}`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a homework question given the solution must use a regex, on that assumption here is an outline to get you going.

If all you have is a URL then @mathematical.coffee's solution will suit. However if you have a chunk of text within which is one or more URLs and you have to locate and change just those then you'll need something a little more involved.

Look at the structure of a URL: {protocol}{address}{item}; where

- {protocol} is "http://", "ftp://" etc.;
- {address} is a name, e.g. "www.google.com", or a number, e.g. "74.125.237.116" - there will always be at least one dot in the address; and
- {item} is "/name" where *name* is quite flexible - there will be zero or more items, you can think of them as *directories* and a *file* but this isn't strictly true. Also the sequence of items can end in a "/" (including when there are zero of them).

To make a regex which matches a URL start by matching each part. In the case of the items you'll want to match the last in the sequence separately - you'll have zero or more "directories" and one "file", the latter must be of the form "name.extension".

Once you have regexes for each part you just concatenate them to produce a regex for the whole. To form the replacement pattern you can surround parts of your regex with parentheses and refer to those parts using \number in the replacement string - see @mathematical.coffee's solution for an example.

The best way to learn regexs is to use an editor which supports them and just experiment. The exact syntax may not be the same as `NSRegularExpression` but they are mostly pretty similar for the basic stuff and you can translate from one to another easily.